# Custom UIButton in UITableViewCell - Remove does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, tableview

I got a custom UIButton in my TableViewCell via:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *ident = @"indet";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease];

    }

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame: CGRectMake( 230.0f, 7.5f, 43.0f, 43.0f)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_bak.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(removeEntry) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = [indexPath row];
    [cell addSubview:button];
    cell.textLabel.text =  [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];
    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);

    return cell;
}
```

I declared the indexPath in my .h for the removeEntry function.

removeEntry:

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[myTable reloadData];
```

myArray is a NSMutableArray.

This way does not work properly.

Everytime I remove an entry at indexPath.row it does remove an entry. But the wrong. It's always one entry above which is getting removed. Even if I do indexPath.row+1 / -1.

Is there another way? The Button should stay in the cell.

I hope it's understandable, sorry, I'm german. :)

Comment: How are you passing the `indexPath` into your `removeEntry` method and how are you calling it?

Answer (score 0):

How many sections are in your table view? It may be a good idea to print out to the console the value of indexPath.row in your removeEntry method. If you click on the first row, is 0 being printed out? Fifth row, is 4 being printed out, etc.

EDIT: Looking at your code, you're storing the indexpath as the tag of the button. In this case, change your removeEntry method to look like this (you can change you return type to whatever you want to return):

```
- (void)removeEntry:(id)sender {
```

And add a colon after 'removeEntry' when you're adding your target:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(removeEntry:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now, inside removeEntry, you can do:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
[myTable reloadData];
```

Comment: Well, it's always different because I count w/ "return [myArray count];"

Comment: If you were to add NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row); to the start of the removeEntry method, it should show you the index of where you had clicked. You firstly want to make sure that the index is correct for the row you clicked. The index should always be 1 minus the row you had clicked on.

Comment: Still deletes the entry above. :(

Comment: Trying printing out button.tag instead of the indexPath and check to see that the values are correct. From the looks of it, it should be working. Maybe edit your original message with more code or paste the relevant code on pastebin. Also, are you sure you're only using a single section?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following peace of code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *ident = @"indet";

     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];
     if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease];

     }
     if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
        for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
          }
     }
     //below here your piece of code.
}
```

The reason for this is, in the method we reuse the cell, that preserves all the subviews added to the cell and only refreshes the text part of the cell.

Hope this will work for you!!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem in my iOS coding with UITableView.
I have fixed it by adding button on cell.contentView and removing it from cell.contentView.

Add button with

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

instead of [cell addSubview:button];

And add following code lines into cellForRowIndexPath() method before add views to cell to remove button from cell.

```
for(UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]){
     [subview removeFromSuperView];
}
```

It would work correctly.